# Relation of JAXB marshaling and DOM Nodes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I would like to ask, are any DOM Nodes created when a JAXB POJO model is created and marshaled?

Example:

```
USAddress address = po.getBillTo();
address.setName( "John Bob" );
address.setStreet( "242 Main Street" );
address.setCity( "Beverly Hills" );
...
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(...);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.marshal( address, System.out );
```

Was there at any moment of the JAXB processing above created any "underlying" DOM Node object graph or marshaling uses other techniques like reflection?

If DOM Nodes are created it would have potential huge impact on XML big structures as whole graph would exist in memory in fact twice - one as POJOs (Address) and one as DOM Nodes (Element("address")).

I am aware that you can marshal into a DOM Node:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.newDocument();
m.marshal( element, doc );
```

But that is not a prove that underlying DOM Nodes are created also for marshaling to a text.

Note:
JAXB Marshaller, respective [MarshallerImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/MarshallerImpl.java) internally uses [XMLSerializer](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.1/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/XMLSerializer.java) which utilize classes like DOMHandler and javax.xml.transform.Transformer but I am not sure if they are used when marshaling (serializing) to a text.

Answer (score 0):

Both the JAXB reference implementation and EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) will not build DOM nodes while marshalling to a non-DOM target.

Comment: Please, could you add something to support your statement? What they use instead? Introspection? Link to sources, especially RI, would be highly appreciated.  
With sources it is tricky, com.sun.xml.* packages are part of rt.jar but with that covered with generally available sources. Sadly cannot just run and debug them, that is why I am asking people here.